# Is it correct to put more articles on the page

Tags: css, html

Example: page that describes 10 sightseeing of the city. I've put each one to the  tag: https://www.best-of-copenhagen.com/en/visit-copenhagen-in-1-2-days
But now I am not sure that it is a correct thing. What should I use to divide them? Section - no... I need put them in some element, if article is wrong - I'll use  just for styles.

> The article tag specifies independent, self-contained content.

well, yes and no... it's independent because each article describe one thing...

Comment: These seem like sections of a single article to me.

Comment: @Witiko I've read: <The section tag defines sections in a document, such as chapters, headers, footers> And don't know if it is a correct to call them sections..

Comment: A subheading counts as a `section`. If you need to put them in an element just for styles, use a `div`.

Comment: @4castle thanks, but it is more correct to use 1 <article> and 9 sections inside it yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page is an `article` which contains multiple `section` tags (chapters). What you did is you put your article inside a `main` tag.

More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp).

Comment: So, I put all content (with h1) into single article. And each of 9 elements inside it - in sections right?